# Springboot sample oidc application which integrates successfully with mockpass (SingPass v2 - NDI OIDC)

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, jwe

like to check if anyone has implemented successfully to  mockpass (SingPass v2 - NDI OIDC) https://github.com/opengovsg/mockpass in Springboot, can help to share the sample project.

I am able to get success from mockpass

ID Token eyJhbGciOiJFQ0RILUVTK0EyNTZLVyIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImVuYy0yMDIyLTA2LTA0VDEzOjQ2OjE1WiIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQkMtSFM1MTIiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlcGsiOnsieCI6IkFXa1BNLVVWV0wxQ1pGUjc2bDl1N1E1NDFDMEEtalFBa3N1Rnd5SFI1d0hWQ1pIeFpjRGdWSzBfVzcyMmxiYkpjTXo0VTZEWGxIV1pobm9CcDFOeDZaVjkiLCJjcnYiOiJQLTUyMSIsImt0eSI6IkVDIiwieSI6IkFUWjFwMHFVclkwZkF5ZDF0U0VrMWlsZEJQYWtWTklBeDJkNVFNZVZPLXp1Q0g3Nk94MTExQWRpbGFLUW9qOVBoY09sb25FUnhWSnJkOWw2ejdmVFBOLUQifX0.0gx20c3CfDl8094ra5CJ7WMEA-CNseP27TXo1_r0nCouVGxD1pr0yJc9RJaRWmwvY8MSjGViruFE9mG0ftriEOLTgSP5O0Ce.5hGMD2PJ2BTp_q7OeckZjg.4ZRAY_71KtDEE4U2T10VXJILIMRASqsf5LA6WhretZwL6cq7p3Lr0E-TP9o7TfNEuxroYb6GEa3iHVs6XjyJilKWYFOw4vJRC2PbLXwztG8TSkPqq7sQju9j7blBzriCDIZJNXO4YLWWZEpkJpdTumXAhvgf4hLLOb0_rSg0PAsLdUOjIPww5vcaR4KTzf8khjrWZFE7n2NzEQFR8EsJsCdXgM45ReuW-WoE4pySB3H1j5JylGfJnrOZd3wS3kGMhxjCSMC_BsuV6uAfswOmgaIdxUxtvFekn1IcKKvX90BCaFjrSCRNSD_a96bnCPK8LQTpkg5iQYkXK9Moi-G_FSqXsTa3H86IExLaRLFnoUGdPGj7yFwQ_KebWiQybkWIBzX_hLzcAx7Qp2T-sYZYv8Sw9P9X3RijvoJDAUZq2lgSfr_MSBXGoRs4QglchNzzi_xDuse9_qR4ChiyRKwMciUU0Ns4BN_KaSjZzddRiE-1D0O4D6lUZ2umjDIeo0ImQV_DKKlVY0HRbVtDWQQCkqOqQm2vptiB1l3f8piKb8rM4TSF5vsZhYirdeb87iOFhP1dt7QItdjmeYadA21czkr-pVvEamqMOAMDC7fTddV42_1-Ho3YM2JeR_zbkYuonrtgdYIwfqNLZeXmDZNiV6HhOldcwyfIve66l5kUn61NsyFnAeRknP_oO586OeRt5OmDmqwEf_EwgtI_n9Q_JQ.LcI3MIKJeh1-dyhxluBP-NJS9ATKWBuUEagcgpO__S0
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024:15:12:16 +0000] "POST /singpass/v2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 1411 "-" "ReactorNetty/1.1.2"

but hitting below error in Springboot application. May I know how i can intercept this and decode the token myself?

2024-01-24T23:12:17.007+08:00 DEBUG 15436 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthenticationWebFilter      : Authentication failed: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: class com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader cannot be cast to class com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader (com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader and com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader are in unnamed module of loader 'app')